# Importing a python module I have created

Tags: python-2.7, module

I know how to import a module I have created if the script I am working on is in the same directory.  I would like to know how to set it up so I can import this module from anywhere.  For example, I would like to open up Python in the command line and type "import my_module" and have it work regardless of which directory I am in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is controlled by `PYTHONPATH`environment variable. Append your module path to PYTHONPATH before you open up Python interpreter and you should be able to import your module.

For more information: [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH)

Answer (score 0):

You can locally import your module with the following command

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, r'PATH OF YOUR MODULE')
import yourmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this work consistently, you can put the module into the lib folder inside the python folder, then you can import it regardless of what directory you are in

Answer (score 0):

You could create pth file with path to your module and put it into your Python site-packages directory.